How to make Xdebug (v3) work with VSCode and Docker (or Podman) on a Windows host?
When I use Xdebug with VSCode (and the PHP Debug extension) locally on my Windows host, it works fine.
But when I try to use Xdebug on a docker/podman container, it doesn't work - it won't stop on breakpoints, even though the connection is succesful.
This is my Dockerfile:
# Use official PHP image with FPM and CLI
FROM php:8.2-fpm

# Install system dependencies and PHP extensions for Laravel
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    git \
    unzip \
    libpq-dev \
    libonig-dev \
    libxml2-dev \
    libzip-dev \
    && docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql pdo_pgsql zip mbstring xml

# Install Xdebug
RUN pecl install xdebug && docker-php-ext-enable xdebug

# Configure Xdebug
RUN echo "zend_extension=xdebug.so" >> /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini \
    && echo "xdebug.mode=debug" >> /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini \
    && echo "xdebug.client_host=host.docker.internal" >> /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini \
    && echo "xdebug.start_with_request=yes" >> /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini \
    && echo "xdebug.client_port=9003" >> /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini \
    && echo "xdebug.remote_port=9003" >> /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini \
    && echo "xdebug.log=/tmp/xdebug.log" >> /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini  \
    && echo "xdebug.idekey=VSCODE" >> /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini 

# Install Composer globally
COPY --from=composer:2.4 /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer

# Set the working directory to /var/www
WORKDIR /var/www

# Copy the Laravel project to the container
COPY . .

# Install Laravel dependencies
RUN composer install --no-interaction --prefer-dist --optimize-autoloader

# Set permissions for storage and cache
RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/storage /var/www/bootstrap/cache

# Expose port 8000 for Laravel's Artisan serve
EXPOSE 8000

# Start the Laravel development server
CMD php artisan serve --host=0.0.0.0 --port=8000

And this is how I build and run the container:
podman build . -t=xdebug

podman run -d -p 8000:8000 -p 9003:9003 xdebug

The output of xdebug_info() shows that the connection is successful and no errors.
I read somewhere that it might have to do with pathMappings: https://github.com/xdebug/vscode-php-debug/issues/653#issuecomment-919385770
Though I tried a few options and it still didn't work (Maybe the issue is related to pathMappings, but couldn't make it work still. What should my values be in this case? It's a Laravel project if that matters)
Update: I tried to edit the pathMappings yet still it won't work. My project is locally on C:/xampp/htdocs/xdebug:
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Listen for Xdebug",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "port": 9003,
            "pathMappings": {
               "/var/www": "C:/xampp/htdocs/xdebug"
            }
        },

And the other way around:
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Listen for Xdebug",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "port": 9003,
            "pathMappings": {
               "C:/xampp/htdocs/xdebug": "/var/www"
            }
        },

But neither worked

What does the output of xdebug_info() show if you're (trying) to debug a PHP file with that call in it?

Yeah, I agree there might be the problem with path mappings. pathMappings should be look like: "localProjectPath": "dockerProjectPath" in your case dockerProjectPath is /var/www. So I guess it's where the problems are lying: client_host and pathMappings

Thank you, where in the docs it says that the left side of the pathMappings is the local path and right side is the docker path? I searched but couldn't find. Could you please link to the docs? Though I tried both: "C:/xampp/htdocs/xdebug": "/var/www" and   "/var/www": "C:/xampp/htdocs/xdebug"and neither work :/. I didn't re-run the container, but it still doesn't work :/

Sorry, I cannot give the link to the docs. I use PHPStorm and there is what I have to configure:
docker-compose.yml: environment: PHP_IDE_CONFIG: "serverName=MinimaList"
then go to PHPStorm's PHP settings -> Servers -> create new Server with the name MinimaList then, Host: localhost, port: 80 and what is more important I think is: "Use path mappings (select if the server is remote or symlinks are used), then I choose File/Directory(local path) and absolute path on the server(in container). I guess VSCode should have something similar.

Do you really have the project name "C:/xampp/htdocs/xdebug"? Also try using in pathMappings: "/var/www": "${workspaceFolder}"

thank you, yes it exists I copy pasted from the Windows Explorer path. I also tried "/var/www": "${workspaceFolder}" but it still won't work :/

Have you tried to use xdebug_break(); function? Also why don't you just create xdebug.ini file and enable it instead writing directly to php.ini (I don't know probably it's the same, but I think it's a good practice to divide config files)? Have you checked php -v, php -m, php --ini?

I was using a code I was given so I'm not sure how to separate xdebug.ini from the php.ini (I'm doing a containerization sort of course). Didn't try xdebug_break() yet, what is it supposed to do?


Just create separate xdebug.ini file with those settings you are used with echo "..." > php.ini, then copy it to /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/.
From the name of the function it should stop on the following line.

